# Await multiple optional tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

Hello I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of writing the async code below. Basically I want to wait on all the tasks, but one of the tasks are optional. It feels needlessly elaborate, thinking if I can do it through some callback but haven't been able to figure it out.

```
var mobile = true;

var task1 = _service.Async1();
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    task1
};

Task<int> task2 = null;
if (!mobile)
{
    task2 = _service.Async2();
    tasks.Add(task2);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var result1 = task1.Result;

if (!mobile)
{
    result2 = task2.Result;
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you need `result1` to process `result2` (where we see "`// Do stuff`")? e.g. Does "`stuff`" use `result1`?

Comment: You can substitute a dummy pre-completed task in the mobile case.
`var results = Task.WaitAll<int>(_service.Async1(), mobile ?Task<int>.FromResult(0) : _service.Async2());`
Now, `results[0]` has the result of `Async1()` and `results[1]` has the result of `Async2()` if it was called; otherwise it is zero.

Comment: @spender Not in this case, no.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah I was trying something like that also, but i don't really like that approach much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to create a list and await all the results at once. Why not `await` it when you need it? If `task2` runs much longer than `task1`, you can at least start processing it, long before `task2` is done.

Something like this:

```
var task1 = _service.Async1();

Task<int> task2 = null;
if (!mobile)
{
    task2 = _service.Async2();
}

var result1 = await task1;

if (!mobile)
{
    var result2 = await task2;
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: One behavior change your code does do I just realized. If `task2` thew a exception and `mobile` is `true` the OP's code would raise the exception from the `Task.WhenAll`, your code would leave the exception unobserved. There is nothing wrong with doing this, it is just a change in behavior that the OP should be aware of. It also lets you leave the scope of the code block with `task2` still running. If a `_service.Async3()` comes along later and requires no other operations are running when it starts this also could cause issues. Again, nothing wrong with it, just be aware of side effects.

Comment: @JonHanna Why? I don't see task1 being awaited prior to the call that starts task2.

Comment: @JonHanna What? No, that's not how `await` works. `await` doesn't *start* the tasks, that's what the async methods themselves do.

Comment: Nope, I'd just misread the order of things. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, thank you! I was so hung up on using WhenAll. I will still use it in the actual code, but break out the optional task and have it's own await.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the heads up!